# How to use AddVelocityConstraintAtNormalizedTime in pydrake?

Tags: drake

I want to constrain \dot{q} at t=0 when using KinematicTrajectoryOptimization, can I use [this constraint](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.planning.html?highlight=addvelocityconstraintatnormalizedtime#pydrake.planning.KinematicTrajectoryOptimization.AddVelocityConstraintAtNormalizedTime)? Are there any examples available?

I see the argument is `pydrake.solvers.Constraint`. However, I have no idea how to use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```py
# Imposes the linear constraint
# lower <= [0 I] * [q] = upper
#                  [v]
# where both lower and upper are numpy arrays of shape (num_positions,)
constraint = pydrake.solvers.LinearConstraint(
    np.concantenate((np.zeros(num_positions), np.eye(num_positions)), axis=1),
    lower, upper)
kinematic_trajectory_optimization.AddVelocityConstraintAtNormalizedTime(constraint, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We try to use KinematicTrajectoryOptimization in an MPC manner (e.g. replanning every 1s and tracking the last solved trajectory between each replanning, reference code [here](https://github.com/vincekurtz/drake_trajopt_examples/blob/main/pendulum_mpc.py)). However, the executed trajectory always pauses (not caused by computation because replay trajectory also pauses) when replanning happens. We think it's caused by the initial $\dot{q}$ being close to 0, so we want to add a constraint on q and $\dot{q}$. We tried the method you provided but found pauses still exist.

Comment: As you mentioned, if the initial qdot is zero, then there will be pause in your action. So I would suggest not to constrain the initial velocity to zero, but instead in an interval [lower, upper]. I updated the code above.

Comment: I noticed that there is no function similar to `UpdateCoefficient` in `WrappedVelocityConstraint`, which means I cannot update the lower and upper bounds according to qdot_measured after the constraint is created. This prevents re-optimizing with an updated constraint on qdot. If I want to resolve KinematicTrajectoryOptimization at every MPC step with an updated qdot constraint, I have to reconstruct a new `KinematicTrajectoryOptimization` and then solve it. Will this reconstruction process be slow for MPC? If so, what is a better way?